# Storing Data on a Local Database

Tags: java, android, local-network

Thanks to contributors from Stackoverflow, I was able to develop my first Android app using Android Studio without any prior knowledge of Java.
It's an unique-interface barcode scanning app (using ZXing) with two EditText fields and an OK button. The two fields are filled with the barcode scanner.

I want to store the data in the two EditText fields on a local database with  two columns (for the two fields) and one table.

**I am not asking for code, I'm just asking for guidelines and pieces of advice to push forward the development of my app.**

Thank you

[image: This is a screencap of my app]

Comment: have you want a code for shared preference?

Comment: What is a shared preference?

Comment: Android provides many ways of storing data of an application. One of this way is called Shared Preferences. Shared Preferences allow you to save and retrieve data in the form of key,value pair

Comment: do you want to save only these 2 fields or do you want to store more data in app database?

Comment: I just want to store the two fields and that's it.

Comment: for only two fields you should use shared preference

Comment: I spent two hours watching and reading tutorials about SharedPref. However, it's not what I need. This method only stores two values and not a full table. The worker that will use the app will do 200 different barcode scans every day. and this data should be stored in a DB table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use Sqlite Database and this is the way you should use it.

DBHelper.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
   public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "barcode";
   public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
   public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_TEXT1 = "field1";
   public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_TEXT2 = "field2";

   private HashMap hp;

   public DBHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      db.execSQL(
         "create table barcode" +
         "(id integer primary key, field1 text, field2 text)"
      );
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS barcode");
      onCreate(db);
   }

   public boolean insertData (String text1, String text2) {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
      contentValues.put("field1", text1);
      contentValues.put("field2", text2);
      db.insert("barcode", null, contentValues);
      return true;
   }

   public Cursor getData(int id) {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from barcode where id="+id+"", null );
      return res;
   }



   public boolean updateBarcode (Integer id, String text1, String text2) {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
      contentValues.put("field1", text1);
      contentValues.put("field2", text2);
      db.update("barcode", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
      return true;
   }
```

Your Activity or Fragment

```
  private DBHelper mydb ;
  mydb = new DBHelper(this);

   //insert
   if(mydb.insertBarcode(EditText1.getText().toString(), 
                       EditText2.getText().toString())){
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    } else{
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }

   //Read
   Cursor getBarcode= mydb.getData(id_to_search);
```

You can also add more function like readfull data from table etc in `DBHelper.java`

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I've already started with Realm based on an advice from someone in the thread. Is it the same thing as SQLite?

Comment: yes its better than sqlite in some scenerios if you have little extra time you can go with realm

Answer (score 0):

Why do you choose a database to store these 2 values?
Did you think about Preference? I think it is more suitable.

Comment: It's a recurring operation (200 times a day) and I need to transfer the data to the ERP, and our ERP only accepts databases. I have no idea about Preference?

Comment: so you want to save the result of 200 times scan? I think you can try with Realm: https://github.com/realm/realm-java. It is quite simple to use

Comment: Alright I'll check this one and get back to you. thankies

Comment: I used realm, I think it's suitable for me. Thank you. However, how can I export my database? Or sync it on the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should read this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Now, decide for yourselves what suits best to your needs keeping in mind all the relevant factors.

Looks like a pet project to me and you just want to store two values,
I would suggest you store them using SharedPreferences

Refer to https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: I spent two hours watching and reading tutorials about SharedPref. However, it's not what I need. This method only stored two values and not a full table. The worker that will use the app will do 200 different barcode scans every day. and this data should be stored in a DB table.